# How to view an image like a cursor on touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a mobile website where I need -in a singular page- to view & hide an icon on touch.
I'd like to have an image which when i touch in a casual point of screen, it appears there and when i touch in another place of the screen it appears where i've now touched. Like a cursor.
It's possible? Do you know how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to put an image where ever someone touches and move the original when they touch again?

Comment: You can get the X, Y coordinates of a click event in javascript. Then you can do whatever you want with that.

Comment: Bill Criswell, yes! But - Daniel Cheng - i really don't know how to do this!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Not sure if it tells you or not.

Comment: @EOF this isn't related to jquery mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're gong for.

```
var $img = $('<img/>').attr({
  'id': 'cursor',
  'src': 'http://www.nicenicejpg.com/50'
});

$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {


  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches["0"];

  $img.css({
    top: touch.clientY - 25,
    left:  touch.clientX - 25,
    display: 'block'
  });

});

$img.appendTo('body');
```

You're just listening for a touchstart on the document and moving the image to the coordinates where the touchstart's first touch event happened.

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/dodipide/6/edit

---

Also, if you wanted it to work with a touch or click you can maybe approach it this way:

```
var $img = $('<img/>').attr({
  'id': 'cursor',
  'src': 'http://www.nicenicejpg.com/50'
});

$(document).on('touchstart click', function (e) {

  var normalizedishEvent = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches["0"] : e;

  $img.css({
    top: normalizedishEvent.clientY - 25,
    left:  normalizedishEvent.clientX - 25,
    display: 'block'
  });

});

$img.appendTo('body');
```

Here is a fiddle of that: http://jsbin.com/dodipide/7/edit

Comment: It runs on mobile devices? "on touch" ?

Comment: According to Chrome's touch emulation it does.

Comment: this won't work on Touch Decives.

Comment: It was a bit of a pain but I got it. Updating my answer: http://jsbin.com/dodipide/6/edit

Comment: You could make this work with touchmove too. You'd want to add `pointer-events: none` to it's CSS to prevent it capturing user touch events.